# Inserting into MySQL table using peewee raises "unknown column" exception

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have the following script:

```
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase('database', user='root')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Locations(BaseModel):
    location_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    location_name = CharField()

class Units(BaseModel):
    unit_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    unit_num = IntegerField()
    location_id = ForeignKeyField(Locations, related_name='units')

db.connect()

for location in Locations.select():
    for pod_num in range (1, 9):
        unit = Units.create(unit_num=pod_num, location_id=location.location_id)
```

table locations has few rows, table units is empty. When I try to start it, I keep getting exception:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'location_id_id' in 'field list'")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is part of SQL script for creating table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`units` (
  `unit_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `unit_num` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `location_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`unit_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`unit_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `location_idx` (`location_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `location_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id` )
    REFERENCES `database`.`locations` (`location_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you change your model's fields after table creation?

Comment: Denis, not I didn't, I've just started to learn peewee, the code above is almost everything I have.

Comment: and how did you create this table?

Comment: With SQL script above (I use Workbench, so it was EER model -> export script -> run script). Just found that renaming column 'location_id' to 'location' fixes the problem :)

Comment: but still I would like to use 'location_id' name (since i'm not allowed to change its name in production db), so question is still actual

Comment: Then you should name your field `location_id_id`, because `ForeignKeyField` automaticly add `_id` suffix at your queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to explicitly specify a column, use `db_column`:

```
class Units(BaseModel):
    unit_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    unit_num = IntegerField()
    location_id = ForeignKeyField(Locations, db_column='location_id', related_name='units')
```

This is documented: http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#field-types-table